# Relation - Set theory proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$When $ A$, B \subseteq \left\{ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}\right\}.  $
$Define $ A $ t $ B to mean that both $\left\vert{A \cup B}\right\vert$ & $\left\vert{A \cap B}\right\vert$ are even. 
Prove that t is a symmetric relation.

I have started by saying that by the subset definition A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} & B = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} therefore $\left\vert{A \cup B}\right\vert$ & $\left\vert{A \cap B}\right\vert$ are even since they have the same cardinality of 5.

Am I  on the right track so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't matter how A and B are defined, its true for any sets

A t B = |A∪B|  and |A∩B|  are both even

= |B∪A|  and |B ∩ A|  are both even

= B t A

(The original question is symmetric wrt A and B. So the relationship is also symmetric)

Answer (score 0):

No.  If $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, that doesn't mean that they are equal to $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

For example, it could be that $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{3,4\}$.  Then
$$|A\cup B|=|\{1,2,3,4\}|=4\quad\hbox{and}\quad |A\cap B|=|\{3\}|=1\ ;$$
these are not both even, so in this case the statement $A\,t\,B$ is false.

On the other hand, if $A=\{1,2,4\}$ and $B=\{1,2,5\}$, then $A\,t\,B$ is true.  **Exercise**.  Give the working to confirm this.

What you have to prove is that if $A,B$ are any subsets at all of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, and if $A\,t\,B$ is true, then $B\,t\,A$ is true.  Here is an outline of the proof, see if you can fill in the missing step.

> Let $A,B$ be subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.
>   Suppose that $A\,t\,B$.
>   This means that $|A\cup B|$ and $|A\cap B|$ are both even.
>   Therefore...
>   Therefore $B\,t\,A$.
>   By definition, $t$ is a symmetric relation.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that $t$ is symmetric you have to show that: $$\forall A \subseteq \{1;5\}\;\forall B\subseteq \{1;5\}\; \big( A\,t\,B \to B\,t\,A \big)$$

That is: If $|A\cup B|$ and $|A\cap B|$ are both even, then $|B\cup A|$ and $|B\cap A|$ are both even, for *any* two **subset/equals** of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.